# Problem joining two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL. I'm having trouble in joining two tables:

```
SELECT e.resourceName
 FROM resources_in_room r
 JOIN resource e ON r.resourceId=e.resourceId WHERE r.roomId=2;
```

Table resources in room:

```
CREATE TABLE  ``resources_in_room` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Quantity` int(11) default NULL,
  `resourseId` int(11) default NULL,
  `roomId` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `resourseId` (`resourseId`,`roomId`),
  KEY `FK36360B9B821B4697` (`roomId`),
  KEY `FK36360B9BC0C935AD` (`resourseId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK36360B9BC0C935AD` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`resourseId`) REFERENCES `resource` (`ResourceId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK36360B9B821B4697`
    FOREIGN KEY (`roomId`) REFERENCES `room` (`RoomId`)
)
```

Table resource:

```
CREATE TABLE  `resource` (
  `ResourceId` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Description` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `Quantity` int(11) default NULL,
  `ResourceName` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ResourceId`)
)
```

Comment: im getting syntax error "Unknown column 'r.resourceId' in 'on clause'"

Comment: Frankly if you can, I would fix the misspelling of resourceid now. This is bound to cause lots of wasted time debugging in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its `resourseId` in your table definition and you are using `resourceId` in query.

This will work

```
SELECT e.resourceName FROM resources_in_room r join resource e on r.resourseId = e.resourceId where r.roomId=2;
```